# non-direct typecasting structs from const to non-const via ifdefs in header file

Tags: c, struct, casting, constants

I want to make struct members accessible for all, but writable only for specially marked code.
Using something like this in header file:

```
#ifdef ALLOW_WRITE
#define EXTCONST
#else
#define EXTCONST const
#endif
```

and placing EXTCONST everywhere in struct typedefs like this:

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
} EXTCONST typename;
```

Corresponding .c file have #define ALLOW_WRITE at beginning, other files have not.

I'm nearly sure that this will work as expected, at least without agressive optimizations turned on.
Two questions:

1) will this work properly with maximum optimizations enabled?

2) is this way correct according to C standards?

NOTE: i know that this can be done via getter functions, but i think that st->a->b looks far better and more intuitive than a_get_b(st_get_a(st))

SUMMARY:
At least two people says that such hidden typecasting is not safe and no one says it is ok.

So i will use "improved" way to do read-noly access check.

```
#ifdef CONST_CHECK
#ifdef ALLOW_WRITE
#define EXTCONST
#else
#define EXTCONST const
#endif
#else
#define EXTCONST
#endif
```

And run the compiler two times for source files in question: one with -DCONST_CHECK to emit all warnings about unauthorized write access, and the second without this flag to produce compiled object file without any possible harmful side affects from compiler optimizations.

Comment: What part do you think might be non-compliant? the `struct` definition or the `ifdef` part?

Comment: I fear the compiler may do some const-related optimizations while in fact the struct is not always const.

Comment: I don't think that it will provide the benefits you hope for.  In fact, I think it is likely to make life uncomfortable.  However, that's not a criticism of its technical feasibility; just on its practical usefulness.

Comment: Then most of the text in the question is irrelevant. You are saying that you have two structures, but one is `const` and one is not. And asking if these are compatible. No, they are not.

Comment: I'm not asking if the structs compatible. The structs ARE compatible as the const keyword doesn't affect binary representation. The question was about the danger of const optimizations.

Comment: Then you *should* ask about the compatibility. The "const optimizations" (and other optimizations) will depend on the type compatibility among the other considerations. Binary representation is pretty much irrelevant when speaking of the language rules.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dangerous way to do, if you include a header using EXTCONST in a source defining ALLOW_WRITE and also in an other source without defining ALLOW_WRITE the two sources will not see the same definitions.

So for instance in a source the compiler can suppose something will not change because const, but because it calls something in the other source changing the value there is an inconsistency.

All the sources have to share the same definitions.

Comment: Yes, the two definitions will differ: one with const keyword and one without it. It shouldn't be a problem from a point of its binary representation, but may be a problem if a compiler thinks the const one can't be altered after being passed to a function that uses it as non-const. The is what i am asking about.

Comment: Yes, so for me this is dangerous and must not be done. Furthermore this is also not easy for someone reading your code. Why do you want to do that ?

Comment: "Why do you want to do that?" - Intuitive read-only access to struct members without syntax hell.

Comment: To add a _const_ is not the hell, it is exactly the reverse, 1) you protect your code against errors (the compiler signal/reject when you try to modify something const) and 2) people looking at your code know something cannot be modified.

Comment: Yes, and this is exactly what i want to do - protect "client" code from accidentally altering some data that it should'nt alter. And i am asking about side-effects from that from unexpected compiler optimizations.

Comment: So write directly the required _const_ in your code without using EXTCONST

Comment: A priori yes, what I missed ? you speak about the NOTE ?

Comment: :( some code should have write access, some code should have only read access. I'm searching an easy way to do that. Just placing const will make the access read-only for all.

Comment: @firk stop to write in C and move to C++, the concepts of class and visibility (_public/protected/private_) are exactly what you need ;-)